# Optimal prediction strategy with unstable parameters

Tags: predictive-models

I got a, at least for me, unusual data set at hand which I employ to create a prediction model for fresh data streaming in. For specific reasons, I only got "one shot" to build the model: That will say, the predictions for the data have to be based on a fixed "algorithm", I cannot update the model after I decided to start the data stream (is it clear, what I mean here?). 
I have already made a decision for the method (logistic regression) and the features (some of which are, however, extravagantly distributed).

In order to find good model parameters, I analyzed the results in random sampling on the training data at my disposal. With not too many observations to train on, a result is that some of the logit's parameters fluctuate too strongly to be taken seriously (Interestingly, the "hitrate" stays robust).

Now my question: How do I find a model that I can trust? I thought of kinda "medianing" the model parameters over the sampling replications. But well, I haven't really heard of this before. I also consider bagging even though it implies to "save" a battery of models which are then applied on the stream data.

For ideas and inputs, I'd thankful.

Comment: By "random sampling" of data do youy mean bootstrap?

Comment: Penalized regression methods pull coefficients towards zero -- this has the effect of controlling their variance. A fully Bayesian model may be appropriate, since you could directly encode prior knowledge of plausible parameter values.

Comment: Yes, Tim, I mean bootstrap indeed. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the idea, General, that sounds plausible, I will check that.